# Create a MS-Access report from user defined filters

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I have written a very basic Access program.  It is pointed at an excel file and generates a list crew initials in a text box (crew_init).  The initials are populated from a column in the excel sheet.  I can select initials from the list (either one, multiple or all) and it will generate a report based on that filter. I would like to add a second text box (fac_ident) and be able to filter by crew_init or fac_ident.  My working solution for using a single text box filter is below.  It is just the public sub for when i click on the generate report button on the form.

```
Public Sub Filter_Click()
  Dim strCrew As String
  Dim ctl As Control
  Dim varCrew As Variant
  
  Set ctl = Me.Crew_List
   
  If ctl.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Must select at least 1 employee. Use Select All checkbox to select all choices.")
    Exit Sub
    Else
   For Each varCrew In ctl.ItemsSelected
    strCrew = strCrew & "'" & ctl.ItemData(varCrew) & "',"
   Next varCrew
   
   'trim trailing comma
   strCrew = Left(strCrew, Len(strCrew) - 1)
  End If

 DoCmd.OpenReport "PM_Logs", acPreview, , "WR_CREW_UNIT IN(" & strCrew & ")"
 
End Sub
```

I have tried adding a string and variant for facIdent but I havent gotten it to work.  I can successfully get another text box to populate the fac_ident data but cannot get the DoCmcd to process both filters.  Pretty new to most this and got a lot of it from web and this site.  Any help would be appreciated.

I have added a string and variant for facIdent.  I can successfully get another text box to populate the fac_ident data but cannot get the DoCmcd to process both filters.  Pretty new to most this and got a lot of it from web and this site.  Any help would be appreciated.  If my strCrew is empty it brings up a report with the whole document no matter what is in my strIdent variable.

```
Public Sub Filter_Click()
  Dim strCrew As String
  Dim strIdent As String
  Dim ctlCrew As Control
  Dim ctlIdent As Control
  Dim varIdent As Variant
  Dim varCrew As Variant
  
  Set ctlCrew = Me.Crew_List
  Set ctlIdent = Me.ident_list
   
  
    For Each varCrew In ctlCrew.ItemsSelected
    strCrew = strCrew & "'" & ctlCrew.ItemData(varCrew) & "',"
   Next varCrew
   
   For Each varIdent In ctlIdent.ItemsSelected
   strIdent = strIdent & "'" & ctlIdent.ItemData(varIdent) & "',"
   Next varIdent
   
   'trim trailing comma
   If strCrew = "" And strIdent = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please select at least one of the filter options!")
        Exit Sub
    Else
     If strCrew = "" Then
        strIdent = Left(strIdent, Len(strIdent) - 1)
     Else
        If strIdent = "" Then
        strCrew = Left(strCrew, Len(strCrew) - 1)
        Else
        strCrew = Left(strCrew, Len(strCrew) - 1)
        strIdent = Left(strIdent, Len(strIdent) - 1)
        End If
     End If
   End If

If strCrew = "" Then
 DoCmd.OpenReport "PM_Logs", acPreview, "FAC_INDENT IN(" & strIdent & ")"
 Exit Sub
 Else
 DoCmd.OpenReport "PM_Logs", acPreview, "FAC_IDENT IN(" & strIdent & ") And WR_CREW_UNIT IN(" & strCrew & ")"
End If
 
End Sub
```

Comment: For dynamically building filter criteria in VBA, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. So the first DoCmd does not work when only FAC_IDENT is the criteria?

Comment: it produces a report but it is not filtered at all

Comment: If FAC_IDENT and WR_CREW_UNIT are number type fields, don't use apostrophe delimiters.

Comment: They are text fields.

Comment: You step debugged? The csv strings are built? I would have to examine db. Could post in a discussion forum that allows attaching files and provide yours.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem after: Change AcPreview,  to AcPreview,,  yes that is a second comma see here for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments